# "Unable to run test .. null object" on Business Rules service on Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, business-rules

When testing my rules on the Business Rules service on Bluemix, I get the following error:

> "Unable to run test
>       Error when executing the ruleset /MyRuleApp/1.0/myrules/1.0
>
> An error occurred while the rule session was called:
>   com.ibm.rules.res.xu.internal.XUException: 
>   An error occurred during
>   the ruleset execution. ilog.rules.engine.IlrUserRuntimeException:
>
> null object when invoking public void myMethod()"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had misconstructed the input parameter (it was missing the opening brace):

```
    "foo": {
        "name": "foo",
        "id": "bar"
    }
}
```

Once I added the opening brace I could run the test successfully.